# Set same time on one field when the time of the other field is selected

Tags: jquery

I want to set same time on some other field when the time of first field is selected. The following is the code I have so far.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#OutletEvents_start_time').datetimepicker({
            datepicker:false,
            format: 'h:ia',
            step:30,

            onSelectTime: function(){

              $('#OutletEvents_end_time').datetimepicker('option', 'minTime', $(this).val());                        
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you are using this plugin ([DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) ) to show the datetimepicker

If so, please rewrite your code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#OutletEvents_start_time').datetimepicker({
        datepicker:false,
        format: 'h:ia',
        step:30,

        onSelectTime: function(current_time,$i) {
            var showTime = current_time.getHours()+":"+current_time.getMinutes();
            $('#OutletEvents_end_time').val(showTime);
        }
    });});
```

Comment: it give me Fri Aug 21 2015 20:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST). I need time only.or if i wants to change time my time picker become enable

Comment: it give me Fri Aug 21 2015 20:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST). I need time only.or if i wants to change time my time picker become enable.or if i enter time 7:00pm it set 7:30 pm on $(OutletEvents_end_time)..it enable to select after 7:00 pm disable before 7:00 pm